# Importing jquery in devextreme application

Tags: jquery, devextreme

Is there a difference between the two below. Are both importing jquery?

import 'devextreme/integration/jquery';

import * as $ from 'jquery';

Comment: Why would you need the import keyword? I'm curious. Isn't simple import via script tag enough?

Comment: Sorry, Rob. I did not get your question. What do you mean my simple import via javascript?